# How to know if a key exists in inner map using java?

Tags: java, dictionary

In the below map how do I know if key3 exists without going through a brute force for-loop and check inside every inner map.
Given that all keys will be unique do we have any library functions doing it?

```
"map": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "innerMap": {
          "key2": "value2",
          "innerMap2": {
            "key3": "value3"
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: You cannot examine the non-existence of key3 without looking everywhere. If that sounds too brute-forcy then you could check the string representation of this json with `.contains("\"key3\":")'`

Comment: But beware that doing a string match on the JSON (or whatever it is) is liable to be fragile.   And also, converting a nested map structure to a string so that you can search using `contains` will be more expensive than a "brute force" search of the map tree.

Comment: @StephenC very correct, unless the json String is the original input, meaning that it's not necessary to convert anything into json.

Comment: Its a HashMap. Based on down votes I guess I'll start working on the for loop XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your picture describes a `Map`, then a "brute-force" tree traversal is your best option.

There is no standard Java SE API for searching nested maps.

@f1sh mentioned the possibility of doing a string search ... assuming that the map is actually JSON.  There are some important caveats:

1. String searching a JSON string (or the result of calling `Map.toString()`) is potentially fragile.  For example, `.contains("\"key3\":")` would give false matches if a *value* in the map contained that search string.
2. Rendering a `Map` to JSON (or whatever) to do a string search will be more expensive than doing the search.
3. A `String.contains` search potentially entails looking at every character in the serialization.  That's just as "brute-force" as a tree traversal.

---

The only alternative that I can think of that is not "brute-force" is to create an auxiliary data structure; e.g. `HashSet` of all (unique) keys in the map tree.  Once created, the set can be queried in `O(1)` ... but creating it is `O(N)` where `N` is the number of (non-distinct!) keys in the tree.

---

Finally, the map tree traversal could be a recursive method rather than (just) a mess of `for` loops.